# PHP string characterization

Tags: php, substring, conditional-statements, letters-and-numbers

I need to specify whether the type of string starts with either 3 digits, 3 letters, or a combination. The string the user types.

The code i have works for letters and numbers, but not for the combinations. What should I do?

```
 $type = substr($value, 0, 3);
 if(is_numeric($type)){
     echo 'starts with 3 digits';
 }elseif(is_string($type)){
     echo 'starts with 3 alphabetic characters';
 }else{
     echo 'undefined type?';
 }
```

Comment: define what sort of combination, if you mean any then surely it's a string that starts with `a-z0-9`?

Comment: your `IF` statement `is_string` is wrong. `X=#` is a string of three characters but is not 3 alphabetical characters.

Comment: I mean anything that does not start with 3 letters or numbers. For ex a2c.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function calls might return unintended results.  I recommend `ctype_` calls for reliability:

```
$type = substr($value, 0, 3);
if(ctype_digit($type)){
    echo 'starts with 3 digits';
}elseif(ctype_alpha($type)){
    echo 'starts with 3 alphabetic characters';
}else{
    echo 'undefined type?';
}
```

p.s. If you want to check if the substring is a combination of letters and numbers, you can can `ctype_alnum()`.